How to lock the lookup value in a table for XLookup to be dragged
As above I am trying to make a formula to just be able to drag it to the left and fill in. I know this can be done in range but wondering if there is a way to do it.
I have tried =XLOOKUP([@Value],Table2[[Value]:[Value]],[Val2],,0) but when dragged to the right it changes the [@Value] and breaks, is there a way to lock it and then let Val2 shift to the right as expected?

@MayukhBhattacharya that does not solve the issue.

Oh yeah correct, I completely missed that OP mentioned about dragged right.

In this case, you may be better off with Vlookup, where you can determine the return column with a number.
=VLOOKUP([@Value],Table2[#All],COLUMN(B1),0)

COLUMN(B1) returns 2. When the formula is copied to the right, the reference changes to C1 and returns 3, etc.
Note that in order to keep the lookup value in [@Value], you must copy and paste the formula instead of dragging it.
If you want to drag it, then you need the more complex reference for the lookup value, assuming it's in Table1
=VLOOKUP(Table1[@[Value]:[Value]],Table2[#All],COLUMN(B1),0)

But if you really want to use Xlookup with the lookup reference locked and the return reference variable when dragging, then use
=XLOOKUP(Table1[@[Value]:[Value]],Table2[[Value]:[Value]],Table2[val2],,0)


For some people, the Vlookup approach with copying instead of dragging might be easier to remember and maintain.

If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.
